# Is there a type parameter matcher in hamcrest?

Tags: junit, hamcrest

I want to test a method like this

```
public List<String> giveStrings();
```

Using hamcrest I can test for the returned type, for example

```
assertThat(giveStrings(), instanceOf(ArrayList.class));
```

But what I want to know is whether it's a List of Strings. Is there an existing matcher for that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So simple answer is `No` because at runtime Java does `type-erasure` so all generics are converted to `Object`. So at runtime your `List<String>` is actually just a `List` or `List<Object>`. The `String` type information is lost.

Consider using

```
IsIterableContainingInOrder.containsInOrder(
               CoreMatchers.instanceOf(String.class),
               ...)
```

Per comment, use [Every](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/core/Every.html)

```
assertThat(myList, Every.everyItem(instanceOf(String.class));
```

Comment: You may want to try http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/ResolvableType.html using `forClass` and `giveStrings().getClass()`

Comment: You can simplify this to `everyItem(instanceOf(String.class))`.